# Domain Name Forwarding not working with github pages

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dig, github

I had my blog on github pages with a custom domain name `blog.tamizhvendan.in` and today I've moved it to a new domain name `www.p3programmer.com` by updating the `CNAME` record with `www.p3programmer.com`. 
The new domain name is working fine.

As it is a breaking change, I would like to have a domain redirection which redirects the old one to the new one. I've configured the same in my DNS Server (BigRock) using their Domain Forwarding System. After that, `tamizhvendan.in` is redirecting correctly to `www.p3programmer.com` but `blog.tamizhvendan.in` resulting in 404 in github pages. By BigRock's documentation, for subdomains will be redirect to path `www.example.com\{subdomain}` i.e in this scenario it should redirect to `www.p3programmer.com\blog` but it is not redirecting.

I've added a `CNAME` record in the `tamizhvendan.in` account with the value pointing to `www.p3programmer.com` but yet I am getting github page's 404 page error.

Here is my dig output of `blog.tamizhvendan.in`

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.1-P2 <<>> blog.tamizhvendan.in +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;; global options: +cmd
;blog.tamizhvendan.in.          IN      A
blog.tamizhvendan.in.   2658    IN      CNAME   www.p3programmer.com.
www.p3programmer.com.   1818    IN      CNAME   tamizhvendan.github.io.
tamizhvendan.github.io. 427     IN      CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  30      IN      A       23.235.44.133
```

Dig output of `www.p3programmer.com`

```
;; global options: +cmd
;www.p3programmer.com.          IN      A
www.p3programmer.com.   1740    IN      CNAME   tamizhvendan.github.io.
tamizhvendan.github.io. 349     IN      CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  30      IN      A       23.235.40.133
```

Answer (score 2):

did you follow the following steps?

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/

Comment: I've followed this only. Its working for `www.p3programmer.com`. But my issue is `blog.tamizhvendan.in` is not redirecting to `www.p3programmer.com` and its showing `404`

Comment: forwarding isn't a dns thing.. it is handled on the webserver

Answer (score 1):

Github seems to only support one external domain per repository, at least according to their documentation [Adding a CNAME file to your repository](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/):

> Note that there can only be one domain in the CNAME file.

So you need a page which answers all request to `blog.tamizhvendan.in` with a 301:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.p3programmer.com/
```